# Write to a LAS file does not work using lasio

Tags: python, las

I have a `.las` file that I am opening using `lasio.read('filename.las')`.

I need to set the negative values for `STRT` (start depth) to 0, which I can successfully view that I have set it to 0. But when I write to a new `las` file and I view the `STRT`, it is still the original negative value and is not modified.

Here is my code:

```
import lasio

las = lasio.read('filename.las')

las.well.STRT.value = 0

las.write('new_filename.las')
```

And here is a snippet of the `well` section in the `las` file:

[image]

The value for `STRT` should reflect 0, but it still shows `-0.7551`

Answer (score 3):

Try to save as using file object, and specify `STRT` and `STOP` parameter as follows:

```
import lasio

las = lasio.read('filename.las')
with open('new_filename.las', mode='w') as f:
    lasio.writer.write(las, f, STRT=0, STOP:10)
```

I don't know why, but `STOP` changed when `STRT` changed.

Example:

```
las = lasio.examples.open('6038187_v1.2_short.las')
print(las.well)

# OUT:
#
# Mnemonic  Unit  Value       Description        
# --------  ----  -----       -----------        
# STRT      M     0.05        FIRST INDEX VALUE  
# STOP      M     10          LAST INDEX VALUE
# ....

with open('new_filename.las', mode='w') as f:
    lasio.writer.write(las, f, STRT=0, STOP=136.6)

las2 = lasio.read('new_filename.las')
print(las2.well)


# OUT:
#
# Mnemonic  Unit  Value       Description        
# --------  ----  -----       -----------        
# STRT      M     0           FIRST INDEX VALUE  
# STOP      M     136.6       LAST INDEX VALUE
# ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
las.write('new_filename.las', STRT=0)
```

The code which writes the LAS file uses the first index curve value in the file, unless explicitly overriden - see the [documentation for `lasio.LASFile.write`](https://lasio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lasio.html#lasio.writer.write).

Perhaps this shouldn't be the default behaviour - I would welcome an issue raised on [GitHub](https://github.com/kinverarity1/lasio/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Alas-writer-code), so that we can track and improve the default behaviour!